# Knockout.js Cannot find template with ID error

Tags: knockout.js

Help, I'm stuck!
I'm trying to do a simple task in knockout.js. Basically, I'd like to have an array of items generate a series of rows in a table. I'm using jquery, and jquery.tmpl.js.  I've done this before many times, but for some reason it is not working. Here's my code.

ASPX Page

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" ClientIDMode="Static" Inherits="EditableGridPrototype._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script src="Styles/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Styles/jquery.tmpl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Styles/knockout-1.2.1.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Styles/knockout.mapping.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.json-2.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Grid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
        <h3>Transactions</h3>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: canSelect" />
        <span data-bind="text: existingTransactions().length" />
        <table width="99%" style="margin-top: 10px" data-bind='template: "existingTransactionsTemplate"'>
            <script type='text/html' id='existingTransactionsTemplate'> 
            {{each(i, tran) existingTransactions()}}        
                        <tr><td>hello</td></tr>          
            {{/each}}                                  
        </script>
        </table>
</asp:Content>
```

The bindings for the checkbox and span do work. The checkbox is checked, and 2 is written out to the page.

Here's my js Grid.js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var transactionsViewModel = {
        canSelect: ko.observable(true),
        existingTransactions: ko.observableArray([
            { canSelect: true, amount: 100 },
            { canSelect: false, amount: 200}])
    };

    ko.applyBindings(transactionsViewModel);

});
```

The template that is used is trivial, I'd like it to just display rows first, so I know it all works. And yes, I put the js files in the Styles folder by accident, this is just a prototype. :)

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I placed a alert($('#existingTransactionsTemplate')); in the Grid.js and it is finding the item in the DOM. For some reason, knockout is not finding it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this:

```
 <span data-bind="text: existingTransactions().length" />
```

to:

```
 <span data-bind="text: existingTransactions().length"></span>
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: @RP Niemeyer  that's wrong but you're right.  good find, must be a regression as this used to work.

Comment: @dove - not sure what you mean.  elements that contain content need to be specified with start and end tags at least when using them with Knockout, otherwise you will run into subtle issues with bindings after this one.

Comment: @RP Niemeyer mean that /> is a valid way to enclose a span and all the content in this case is within that span via the template.